# Interpreting binary logit model?

Tags: probability, ordered-logit

I have some output from a binary logit regression and I have some difficulties interpreting it properly. Particularly I would like to know whether the coefficient of “male” tells me about the probability of outcomes 0 and 1 and what role the intecept plays in that example. Dependent Variable is political preference.

```
            "Estimate" "Std. err." "z-score"
(Intercept) −5.183     1.094       −4.738
Male         0.652     0.318        2.053
```

Answer (score 0):

In a logistic regression, you model the logit of the outcome, you can model the probability of the DV by exponentiating. So, how have you coded "political preference"? Suppose 1 = Republican and 0 = Democratic. Then

$\text{logit}(Pr(D)) = -5.183 + 0.652*M$

and

$Pr(D) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{(5.183 - 0.652M)}}$